# Sum of Double type in java

Tags: java, double

I have a smple sop line as :

```
 System.out.println(0.0000877979+0.3067846127);
```

The output of above line is : `0.30687241060000003`

But the expected is : `0.3068724106`

I doubt,how come extra `0000003` at last came.

Comment: This sum operation is calculated using double and result is printed as double. The extra 0000003 is result of float point arithmetic. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to understand what a `double` number is: it's a binary floating point number. As such, it can't represent all *decimal* numbers exactly. For example, take the number 0.2. There's no finite binary representation of that - just as there isn't a finite decimal representation of 1/3.

If you're interested in *decimal digits* then you should use `BigDecimal`. However, that may not actually be appropriate for what you're trying to achieve. What do the numbers *mean* in your case? Are they measured values from natural properties (weight, height etc) or are they "artificial", naturally decimal values such as financial ones? This affects which type you should use.

`BigDecimal` is different from `double` in three important ways:

- It supports *arbitrary precision* (as many digits as you have memory for, basically)
- It has a floating *decimal* point instead of a floating *binary* point. So while it still can't represent "a third" exactly, it *can* represent decimal values exactly.
- It's a class type rather than a primitive. That's not important in terms of what numbers can be represented, but it's important to understand as a difference between the two types.

When constructing a `BigDecimal`, it's important that you start with accurate values - converting a `double` to `BigDecimal` is almost always a mistake. So if you've got user input as text, that's fine:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("0.0000877979");
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("0.3067846127");
System.out.println(bd1.add(bd2)); // Prints 0.3068724106
```

In other cases you may start with another `BigDecimal`, or possibly an integer.

Comment: Thanks...they are of artificial type.I should go with BigDecimal

Comment: @NirdeshSharma: Right, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of using floating-point arithmetic in a binary environment. Look at this  [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard for more information.

You should use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class for pecision.

Use [BigDecimal.valueOf(value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29) to convert the `double` to `BigDecimal`.

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal, using the double's canonical string representation provided by the Double.toString(double) method.

Comment: +1. You were faster ;)

Comment: The binary part is the important bit here. `double` could be as long as you like, but it still wouldn't be able to represent 0.1 exactly.

Comment: And converting from a `double` to a `BigDecimal` is probably a bad idea - you'd want to convert from the original *string* representation, otherwise you've already lost information.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal due to the limited nature of floating point numbers (`float` and `double` in Java). Please learn about floating point arithmetics (IEEE 754).

To get exact numbers use `BigDecimal` in Java.

Comment: `BigDecimal` is a floating point type too. The important part is the *base* of the type (and the fact that `BigDecimal` is arbitrary precision, but the base is more important).

Comment: @JonSkeet extended my answer accordingly to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(0.0000877979);
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(0.3067846127);
System.out.print(bd.add(bd1).setScale(10,0));
```

Comment: NO! If you use the constructors taking `double`s as arguments, you fall trap to the imprecision of `double`!

Comment: This will produce 0.3068724107 but i want 0.3068724106

Comment: System.out.print(bd.add(bd1).setScale(10,1));

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact result, you can try like this,

```
BigDecimal b1= BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0000877979);
BigDecimal b2= BigDecimal.valueOf(0.3067846127);
System.out.println(b1.add(b2));
```